# Meteor full page template

Tags: templates, meteor

Im using Meteor. I'm trying to have a full page template (including the `body` and `head` tags). Because one is to be for the mobile version.

I tried having

```
{{> desktop}}

<template name="desktop">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
</template>

<template name="mobile">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
</template>
```

I get a syntax error with this (Due to the >desktop handlebar)also How would I switch between the two templates? (Meteor adds the `<html>` tags and a bunchload of `script` tags so its somewhat problematic

Answer (score 2):

Create `desktop_head` and `desktop_body` templates instead for desktop, do the same for mobile.

Then, at run-time, add the templates to the body and head tags based on your device. Do not introduce additional head and body tags because that's not how it works, you need to have a single body / head...

Furthermore, you might want to consider a responsive design instead...

Comment: this seems awefully complicated for such a simple use. I decided to create two meteor projects and use one mongodb.

Comment: I think your solution is more complicated than Tom's answer.